# Swift Framework with FMDB dependency

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, fmdb, cocoa-touch

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I'm attempting to create a Cocoa Touch Framework. The framework will contain database manipulation classes and is dependent upon FMDB.

What I've done and tried so far is to create a Cocoa Touch Framework project, insert my classes (Swift) in and add the FMDB source (the Objective-C headers and implementations). At this point, my FMDB dependent classes are yelling that they need their precious FMDB, but it's nowhere to be found.

I've attempted to solve this issue by adding "FMDB.h" to my umbrella header, but that doesn't seem to work; I get the *"Include of non-modular header inside framework module"* error. Additionally, I've tried to set the *"Allow non-modular headers"* flag to YES, to lack of success.

Lastly, I've tried to create a modulemap, as seen on some of the answers on SO.

Looks like this:

```
module FMDBModule {
header "/Users/X/Documents/Projects/X.DatabaseManager/DatabaseManager/FMDB/FMDB.h"
export * }
```

This modulemap is put inside a Modules directory, in the same root location the .xcodeproj resides. Also, the Header Search Paths field of the Target Build Settings has been set to ***$(PROJECT_DIR)/Modules***, which is the directory the modulemap resides in.

This also proved to be fruitless, as the "FMDB.h" in my umbrella header's still not recognised. I've attempted to use a import FMDB statement on top of the dependent class, but I receive the "Not found" error. The interesting thing here is that, if I write ***import FMDatabase***, CMD + Click will lead me to the class definition, but Xcode will error out with "Not found".

I'm out of ideas at this point, but I would very much like to proceed with this idea of modularising my code base.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi @D6mi did you got the solution for this, am also into the same issue

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the slow response. I haven't found a solution to this one I'm afraid, so I've used Carthage with the framework.

Comment: @Sankari, reiterating on this one. With the advent of Swift Package Manager, this issue is easily solved by creating a Swift Package with FMDB added as a dependency.